# Some media queries are not working on mobile devices but are working on desktop - Viewport should be correct

Tags: media-queries

I've been trying to find an answer to this issue for awhile and am having some trouble. I am using a wordpress responsive theme and the basic responsive structure is working. But when I go to add my own queries, they don't seem to be working consistently on mobile but they all work fine on the desktop. For example, I have display:none; set for both screen and devices on an image. I'm looking at three mobile devices, iphone, galaxy and htc one. The iphone and galaxy remove this image, but the htc one does not. The device specific media queries are not working on either of the android devices but is working on the iphone.

When I create a media query that I want to use for both screen and devices I use this, for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width : 320px) { styles here }
```

If I want to target only devices I use this, for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px) and (max-device-width:480px){styles here}
```

Here is are the styles:

```
/* //// MEDIA QUERIES //// */

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
.wpb_single_image.home-paint-roller img {
display:none;
}

}

/* //// Device Only //// */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px) and (max-device-width:480px)    {

.service-images ul {
display:none;
}

.what-they-said ul {
display:none;
}
}
```

This is the viewport I'm using:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Here is the url:
http://snlpainting.wpengine.com/

I would appreciate the help, I've been looking for a long time for an answer and finally decided to see if I could get some help. Thanks!!